# Changing tabs using menu items in actionbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have been using a TabLayout till now to navigate between different tabs in my application. I need to remove the Tablayout and navigate between the tabs using menu items in the toolbar.

This is the code I have been using.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

What code should I add in the OnOptionsItemSelected() section?.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have to navigate to position "p" then,

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(p);
```

that's it.

And no need to add any listener.